# Nginx .zip files return 404

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I have set up Nginx as a reverse proxy for Node and to serve my static files and user uploaded images.

Everything is working beautifully except that I can't understand why Nginx can't find my .zip files.  Here is my nginx.conf.

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes 1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
   worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {

include mime.types;
proxy_cache_path /var/www/web_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=ooparoopaweb_cache:8m     max_size=1000m inactive=600m;

sendfile on;

upstream *******_node {
    server 172.27.198.66:8888 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
    #fair weight_mode=idle no_rr
}

upstream ******_json_node {
    server 172.27.176.57:3300 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
}

server { #REDIRECT ALL HTTP REQUESTS FOR FRONT-END SITE TO HTTPS
    listen 80;
    server_name *******.com www.******.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server { #MOBILE APPLICATION PROXY TO NODE JSON
    listen 3300 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /*****/*******/json_ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /*****/******/json_ssl/server.key;

    server_name json.*******.com;

    location / {    
        proxy_pass http://******_json_node;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
        proxy_send_timeout 90s;
        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
        proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    }
}

server { #******.COM FRONT-END SITE PROXY TO NODE WEB SERVER
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /***/***/web_ssl/********.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /****/*****/web_ssl/myserver.key;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;

    location / {
        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript;
        proxy_pass http://mydomain_node;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
        proxy_send_timeout 90s;
        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
        proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    }
}

server { #ADMIN SITE PROXY TO NODE BACK-END
    listen 80;

    server_name admin.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mydomain_node;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
        proxy_send_timeout 90s;
        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
        proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    }
}

server { # SERVES STATIC FILES

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /**/*****/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /****/******/server.key;

    server_name static.domain.com;
    access_log static.domain.access.log;

    root /var/www/mystatic/;

    location ~*\.(jpeg|jpg|png|ico)$ {

        gzip  on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml
        application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/png image/jpeg
        application/zip;
        expires 10d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;

    }

    location ~*\.zip {
        #internal;
        add_header Content-Type "application/zip";
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=gamezip.zip";
    }
}
}

include tcp.conf;
```

Tcp.conf contains settings that allow Nginx to proxy websockets.  I don't believe anything contained within it is relevant to this question.  I also want to add that I want the zip files to be a forced download.

Comment: May I add that is the zip file is renamed to .jpeg/.png/.jpg/.ico then nginx will find the file.

Comment: When looking at the logs I see that nginx is trying to open a file at 012/11/23 11:28:28 [error] 9239#0: *1298 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/gamezip/G3zZ4pBq0BCeKb3o13EPKC4AaT63JvbnwOwQsV4p.zip" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 121.140.215.179, server: static.ooparoopa.com, request: "GET /gamezip/G3zZ4pBq0BCeKb3o13EPKC4AaT63

but I have specified that it is to look in /var/www/gamezip.

Comment: **`gzip_types ... image/png image/jpeg application/zip;`!**   Do you realize what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting it like this:

```
location ~ .*\.zip$ {
    add_header Content-Type "application/zip";
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=gamezip.zip";
}
```

Also, if the above does not work, as a hack, try redefining the root inside the location:

```
location ~ .*\.zip$ {
    root /var/www/mystatic/;
    add_header Content-Type "application/zip";
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=gamezip.zip";
}
```

Finally, for the love of $DEITY, please remove application/zip from your gzip types:

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml
    application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/png image/jpeg **application/zip;**
```

It is useless since a .zip file is already compressed!